# how to convert img tag to evernote en-media

Tags: android, evernote

I'm working with evernote api on android, and want to translate html to enml. How to translate img to en-media? for example:
img:

```
<img src="imagePath"/>
```

to en-media, do i need to downloading the images myself and replace the image tag to en-media myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to download the image and replace the image tag to en-media with hash and type attributes.

You can see the spec [here](http://dev.evernote.com/start/core/enml.php).